# Protect client side database like TaffyDB

Tags: mysql, cordova, taffydb

I have to develop an application for smartphones using HTML/CSS/JS (for PhoneGap) and I have to store data somewhere.

After some research, I found TaffyDB (http://www.taffydb.com/) that exactly does the job except on one point : **security**.

I don't want someone to take all my data just by saving the JS file so is there a solution to protect it ?
Or if I want to keep my data private, do I have to use an usual database (like MySQL) coupled with a PHP script that I call via Ajax ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TaffyDB can be used on Server-Side with a number of [server-side solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_server-side_JavaScript_solutions), but you will have to control the output on your application to include just the data.

In general, unless you plan to use a javascript server-side solution, I would say you cannot make it "secure", and even if you use non sensitive data on your front-end, I would highly recommend you go through the [OSWAP guide](https://www.owasp.org/images/5/56/OWASP_Testing_Guide_v3.pdf) before writing any code to determine if it is secure or not.

Comment: I ended up storing my data in a MySQL database. My application calls a simple PHP script in Ajax with jQuery. I hope Apache Cordova handles ajax calls to an external server...

Comment: I'd say that is probably a safe approach. The OSWAP guide is still abstract enough to point out a few helpful tips though.